# In the Hanon piano exercises, why is there a beam joining two groups of 16th notes?

Tags: piano, notation, rhythm, keyboard, beaming

The first measure of the Hanon exercises has a set of four 16th notes that make up a quarter note, and another set of 4 16th notes that make up another quarter note.  This adds to 2 quarter notes for the measure, which is the time signature.

But why are the first 4 sixteenth notes joined to the next 4 sixteenth notes with a line?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that that's just to do with the typesetting and not at all to do with anything technical. If anything, then I think that it may be to help you group those 8 notes together and think about them as a group.